# How to read structure variable from workspace to Gui in matlab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

i am trying to get a structure variable from workspace to gui edittext box which i did successfully after many trials, but i came across another problem while displaying the variable.

I am getting this warning after applying my string to a text box.'**Single line Edit Controls can not have multi-line text**' so i changed the edit box property max step to 2 so that i can avoid this error.

my intension was to display the variable value as the simulation is under process but i am unable to do it. After the completion of simulation if and only if i click on the edit box after a while i am getting the value displayed but that too is like a scroll down display.

```
function edit3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

simout=evalin('base','simout');
L = length(simout);
vars = cell(1,L);
[vars{1:L}] = simout.signals.values;
set(handles.edit3,'string',vars);
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Anyone please help me out with this issue asap.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your edit box to display values as the simulation progresses, you have to call

```
set(handles.edit3,'string',currentValue);
```

*during* the simulation (where currentValue is the value you want to display).

> After the completion of simulation if and only if i click on the edit
>   box after a while i am getting the value displayed but that too is
>   like a scroll down display.

You see the value only after you click because that code is inside a "callback" function, which is called when you interact with the edit box.
If you want to display that value immediately at the end of your simulation, let your simulation execute the *set* command to update the edit box when it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You might have the problem, that the Matlab process doesn't update the screen while running.

It might be neccesary to include `drawnow` after your updates. But that will only help when the window is in foreground.

Personally I always write stuff to a log file and display it outside of matlab.